# Get wrong output in python Singleton design pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, singleton, private-members

I was making a Singleton design pattern and everything goes fine.

Look at the code below:

```
class Singleton():
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
            cls.instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls.instance

s1 = Singleton()
s2 = Singleton()

print(s1 is s2)
# True
```

But this is not Singleton because user can use `delattr(Singleton,'instance')` between creating `s1` and `s2` and with this simple function `s1 is s2` returns False

So I decided to change `instance` to `__instance` (to stop user using `delattr(Singleton,'instance')`) but when I do that I get False when printing `s1 is s2`
(My new code (__instance))

```
class Singleton():
    def __new__(cls):
        if not hasattr(cls, '__instance'):
            cls.__instance = super().__new__(cls)
        return cls.__instance

s1 = Singleton()
s2 = Singleton()

print(s1 is s2)
# False
```

But where is the problem?
Why when I change `instance` to `__instance` the result I get is False?

(I know other methods of creating Singleton I  Just want to know what is different in `instance` and `__instance` when I'm in the class and `__instance` is not private for myself)

Answer (score 1):

Python name mangles the variable. Its called "_Singleton__instance" in the class `__dict__`. You could use that name instead or use an exception handler for the assignment. In that case, python does the mangling for you and it would work for subclasses of Singleton also.

```
class Singleton():
    def __new__(cls):
        # could do this ....
        #if not hasattr(cls, '_Singleton__instance'):
        #    cls.__instance = super().__new__(cls)
        #return cls.__instance
        try:
            return cls.__instance
        except AttributeError:
            cls.__instance = super().__new__(cls)
            return cls.__instance

s1 = Singleton()
s2 = Singleton()

print(s1 is s2)
```

Of course its still easily defeated

```
delattr(Singleton, "_Singleton__instance")
s3 = Singleton()
print(s1 is s3)
```

Python is a very dynamic language and if someone wants to hurt themself, then have at it!

Comment: Thanks a lot but just a question: you mean python saves attributes of class like this?: `'_'+CLASSNAME+ATTRIBUTE`

Comment: @Ramin-RX7 - Yes, but only if the name starts with double underscores. So `"attribute"` is just `"attribute"` but `"__attribute"` becomes `"_CLASSNAME__attribute"`. Its meant primarily to avoid name collisions between a parent and inherited class. See [Private variables](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)